# Pandas rolling().std() stuck in 0.0 after outlier

Tags: pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df3 = pd.DataFrame([0.04810771078125643, 0.0652101133693269, 0.02076908904792964, 0.05627707076988381, -0.005862996489416603, 0.07774174565661258, 0.0029885934174610947, 0.009518321055701454, 0.1105499817991784, 0.14819521537400218, 0.20605598645295742, 0.1885158817764897, 0.07497632608031278, 0.11810347702193046, 0.007021861762178953, -0.028884250862363837, -0.016257677240184877, -0.056715321015071665, -0.04786542257906791, -0.041886257497215265, 0.04951571733673249, -0.040397726952907734, -0.002270034034548094, 0.0799644008521724, 0.16546390451146364, 0.04744143827157654, 0.0890253424224255, 0.18760186856463362, 0.043731699035837734, 0.05046795081185698, 0.02264244919401265, 0.06035559337165443, 0.001024730285920049, 0.049148554737845795, -0.030583136571872383, 0.01223311511445285, -0.031699368085984114, 0.03373801417858714, 0.1143423304324727, 0.04218968381641393, 0.03484786158444362, -0.005844399297150011, 0.07275788448760953, -0.028926052163847662, 0.021862978508348063, -0.04355087589551836, -0.005581888568248592, -0.04333910615889465, 0.06890953163945052, 0.03267691622959628, 0.08453327814425625, 0.02202256182978313, 0.0004122300099288663, -0.00624240435104436, -0.014950739678406964, 0.0009675009001304342, -0.02644347403171114, 0.02456502844323759, 0.042811295702752175, 0.12387038189917, 0.09010971293008112, 0.23872856880713936, 0.23445099129594454, 0.11651039074175915, 0.1344441041512155, 0.10938991176854172, 0.2138764344243745, 0.07137420269904692, 0.10770319927363835, 0.23759970822792376, 0.23314833117064448, 0.2067783208839305, 0.2106360518628203, 0.17121548837930184, 0.08344378638223546, 0.0905616236483005, 0.03188583498726093, 0.06846020699257942, 0.004151401149601738, 0.06577515428712444, -0.011835602485387078, 0.01844722160934814, -0.017232497627695187, 0.03380544466927249, 0.1015601748861771, 0.14604244280075002, 0.025165118542728633, -0.008587894419213121, 0.008898777264430193, 0.05888799128834346, -0.015879039931667102, 0.038222734190929655, 0.01758409470880442, 0.052557395078858524, 0.06530617253800304, 0.027295532206117648, 0.0306631342319581, 0.06619148113693683, 0.064711039918664, 0.04304928641422032, 0.07899401170288685, 0.04056975765698974, 0.06597845068261034, 0.14752945687035668, 0.08207970442983513, 0.08901593793998426, 0.11555603360665315, 0.10509171159372781, 0.08039459158049483, 0.16143640752946997, 0.037517291589437396, 0.018524196562234495, 0.010499589838820125, 0.07734333548581686, -0.0011966392579159657, 0.05242657863548532, -0.03226429636832931, 0.000654919937393637, -0.061823238836554203, -0.018841805059826272, -0.05429950047942815, -0.010711517472173037, -0.0403755406994839, 0.06346570885450263, 0.008058756189585053, -0.01810486670932912, 0.007891758665062226, 0.046008650906442905, -0.004869642056563619, -0.07912355074355631, -0.0775564477405906, 0.006422862718696513, -0.0254028924616409, -0.15083412930014217, -0.036508067339285855, 0.01982069535895556, 0.059530882959960826, 0.08155051259596023, 0.12796006592838763, 0.11610283692957439, 0.139269427929804, 0.1459496337938567, 0.17168821248320354, 0.14657157439695928, 0.15947952569612656, 0.17798480520332227, 0.191433177713942, 0.2679211126962, 5627301222199.108, 6028439617087.683, 0.0776416783872972, -0.15325211972369018, -0.37675285091308763, -0.1876778333460476, -0.23011973436975613, -0.2594060398741544, -0.08258867140078371, 0.12183596775439592, -0.09646921106800667, -0.12340327558493287, -0.08816019613398646, -0.04359466677408608, -0.00700715847108014, -0.03691329288838151, -0.05331288497453571, -0.03195105765341541, -0.09349417736330745, -0.030023993134620657, -0.09337957008268485, -0.04140915967813463, -0.06699033738504752, -0.013207237554931004, -0.07843029926076672, -0.028603278225391892, -0.08509660523204332, 0.008947366757291561, -0.04190287198193737, 0.01586870613791104, -0.022913449895198276, 0.06571616347317309, -0.021900026423405817, 0.028512740433412086, -0.010359636202084733, 0.026180893811231103, -0.058366725347592935, -0.09152467958871817, -0.07298804614739414, -0.10402790157085012, -0.08170925281082868, -0.015153949111577695, 0.012613343988873555, 0.016158505018100445, 0.10044135323450971, 0.0267772175282329, -0.017281780658433447, 0.007589405759384257, 0.07961230986065232, -0.006441948796269106, -0.015595163657378588, -0.0029688620464165226, -0.001865436287310408, 0.00685108746603718, 0.08383811692608183, 0.05637381159281189, 0.05452263919043426, 0.051914127232449994, 0.07800795441574261, 0.007868840642200139, 0.049713691126910695, -0.021605154335954786, 0.04735191833931762, 0.09889464263342297, 0.04618991955282502, 0.013771897123080174, 0.07907681598308244, 0.0564019679208352, -0.020341121336213137, -0.056979875342588665, -0.0931735784638613, 0.0023409260057884775, -0.025290079540396887, -0.02790661730472928, -0.07913813303769102, -0.060788657610573754, -0.10872241795865936, -0.05464826887781504, -0.07389934553819671, -0.04219544604406554, -0.07990574773213362, -0.021089388554776194, 0.0065513802003133725, -0.023241495200739787, 0.025254985861880505, 0.023884699800815246, 0.06865774456693101, 0.02367271933476347, 0.003030215000537393, 0.035490964854638485, 0.14241073839797957, 0.009880075413908016, 0.045780270772878315, 0.15248905752695813, 0.05935202594108105, 0.08826005757363811, 0.061900561145380784, 0.08819393092682253, 0.024369354730746823, 0.07581429495764026, 0.13287132021621095, 0.14571240538545327, -0.042757880974733944, -0.1452299205063963, -169.93331476436367, 0.006467936437881716, -0.055433670933421234, 0.024299866397362507, -0.04443406943238287, 0.017707787089531305, -0.03548254835196789, 0.027496454199535832, -0.04836232927097839, 0.0036097215005425867, -0.01877260815379003, -0.03848780423525695, -0.04976312360716227, 0.019744516861113906, 0.04408079002546292, 0.025756628513665933, 0.05619442277605671, 0.0707852927736979, 0.10635910587477355, 0.08335598797996507, 0.14489401581019604, 0.1322649363490686, 0.07535452338596417, 0.021213943225911455, -0.022059411831900164, -0.08739174326283712, -0.05775167797091828, -0.021323945088034386, 0.055298205358075336, -0.011002766139377599, 0.023828647926716198, 0.04400914995669093, -0.016941166295338546, -0.020131929669357538, -0.04155686438016351, 0.022266110795840014, -0.058069725356853216, -0.03092512388198525, -0.10530323989540032, -0.122802334058923, -0.09736279723837524, -0.07777553258771629, -0.06385520151292515, -0.10450970815925294, -0.0276385922311423, -0.05059848230394694, -0.1231232290269715, -0.04071954997443793])


df3['std']=df3[0].rolling(50).std()

df3['std'][100:120]

100    0.084792
101    0.084556
102    0.083737
103    0.083425
104    0.082065
105    0.081071
106    0.079321
107    0.078773
108    0.078464
109    0.079112
110    0.079515
111    0.076462
112    0.073358
113    0.073109
114    0.073568
115    0.073447
116    0.071820
117    0.072614
118    0.075087
119    0.070905

df3['std'][250:270]

250    0.0
251    0.0
252    0.0
253    0.0
254    0.0
255    0.0
256    0.0
257    0.0
258    0.0
259    0.0
260    0.0
261    0.0
262    0.0
263    0.0
264    0.0
265    0.0
266    0.0
267    0.0
268    0.0
269    0.0
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX1vq.png)

There is outlier in the data. The rolling().std() stucks in 0.0 to the end of series.
If I use rolling.apply(lambda z: np.std(z)) it is ok, but apply is slower. Is there any method to use panda's std in such a situation?

pandas (1.4.1)

numpy (1.22.2)

Comment: From pd docs: The default ``ddof`` of 1 used in :meth:`Series.var` is different than the default ``ddof`` of 0 in :func:`numpy.var`.

Comment: I tryed df3['std']=df3[0].rolling(50).std(ddof=0)
But it gives same behavior  - stuck in 0.0

Comment: Yes, but the results at the first are equal in this way.

Comment: .apply(np.std) is a bit more efficient.